# Best way to read a property from a MovieClip?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I got a .fla file, where inside I have some movieclip instances placed in the scene. I need to iterate through them and gather some data, like position, name, and custom properties.

These custom properties, I don't know how to pass them, I know one way that works so far is to use the accessibility properties panel (Flash Pro CC), and then in the code I can just read them. However there should be a better way I assume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood correctly your question and what you have said in your comments about the answer of @Aaron, you have an swf file, which you load dynamically, and you want to get/set some of its MovieClips properties, if it's the case, take this example :

**MyMC.as :**

```
public class MyMC extends MovieClip 
{       
    private var timer:Timer;
    private var rotation_speed:int = 1;

    public function MyMC() {
    }
    public function set_Rotation_Speed(_rotation_speed:int): void {
        this.rotation_speed = _rotation_speed;
    }
    public function get_Rotation_Speed(): int {
        return this.rotation_speed;
    }
    public function start_Rotation(): void {            
        this.timer = new Timer(500, 10);
        this.timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, on_Timer);
        this.timer.start();
    }
    private function on_Timer(e:TimerEvent): void {
        this.rotation += this.rotation_speed;
    }
}
```

Then, in my `swf.swf` I have an instance of that MovieClip.

I loaded the `swf.swf` using this code :

```
var loader:Loader = new Loader()
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, on_SWFLoad);
    loader.load(new URLRequest('swf.swf'));
```

And to set/get some of my MovieClip properties, I did :

```
function on_SWFLoad(e:Event): void 
{       
    var swf:DisplayObjectContainer = DisplayObjectContainer(loader.content);
    var num_children:int = swf.numChildren;

    for(var i:int = 0; i < num_children; i++)
    {           
        var child:MovieClip = MovieClip(swf.getChildAt(i));

        // get the name
        trace('name : ' + child.name);

        // set the position
        child.x = child.y = 100;

        // get the class name, in my case it's MyMC
        var class_name:String = getQualifiedClassName(child);

        // get all the details of the child
        trace(describeType(child));

        child.set_Rotation_Speed(45);
        child.start_Rotation();

        trace(child.get_Rotation_Speed());      // gives : 45           
    }

    addChild(loader);
}
```

You can use the [`describeType()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#describeType()) function To get all the properties of your instance.

Hope that can help.

Comment: So the new symbol I create and place in the stage (inside Flash Pro CC) would be using as a class MyMC instead of MovieClip, right?. In that case, how can I assign MyMC as class for the symbol?. I've tried to do it but it's a bit clunky how it works, it asks me to save a new .as file, but then it never uses it.

Comment: @Artemix Yes, that's right, it's a subclass of MovieClip. If you need to edit that class, do it, otherwise, Flash will generate it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can set properties on timeline instances from code. There's nothing special about this. For example:

1. Place an instance of a library symbol on a keyframe
2. Give it an instance name in the Properties panel, for example "myInstance"
3. On the same keyframe put some code that refers to it, such as `myInstance.color = "red"`

You can also create and assign custom properties by making the symbol a component:

1. Right-click on the symbol in the library and choose "Component Definition"
2. Add custom properties in the Parameters table. It's now a component symbol.
3. On the timeline, place an instance of the symbol and use the Properties panel to set its parameters.

You can do a lot more with components if you want, such as live preview and compiled components. More info can be found here here: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/learning_guide/components/part03.html

Comment: The components definition section would do great, I just need to be able to read those values from the code. I'm not using Flash to code, only to create some motions.

Comment: You can refer to them from code using the instance name and the property name, for example: `myInstance.color`

Comment: Yeah that didn't work. I need to clarify, that I'm reading the property inside my IDE, not inside the timeline. I'm loading my SWF dynamically and then I'm trying to read the value there. For example, I added a myVar with a default value of "asd", then inside my code I do unit1.myVar and it returns undefined.

Comment: "Inside my IDE" meaning what? In a .as file? In any case, it should work, you are probably having timing or scope issues. Post some code.

Comment: By "Inside my IDE" I meant that I'm not trying to access the component value from the timeline, which could have a different scope/behavior. I'ts been some time since I had to write code inside the timeline. (thanks God).

Comment: But you specifically said "I have some movieclip instances placed in the scene" -- you don't mean on the timeline? I think you need to expand your question with code and more specific context and what you are trying to do. Accessing MovieClip properties by code is exactly like any other object, especially if you aren't using the timeline, so I'm not sure what you are having trouble with.

Comment: Yes they are on the timeline, but I'm not accessing them via code inside the "actions" section of the timeline.